# How to add positional options for existing arguments in argparse

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm dealing with a (Python 3.x) script (written by someone else) where the input and output are currently specified with flagged optional arguments like so:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', nargs='?', type = argparse.FileType('r'),
                    default=sys.stdin, dest='inputfile')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output-file', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    default=sys.stdout, dest='outputfile')
```

I'd like to upgrade this script so that the input and output file can be specified as positional arguments while maintaining the existing flag arguments for backwards compatibility.  I'd also like to intelligently handle the potential conflicts which might come from mixing the flagged argument with the positional argument (i.e. if only one of `-i` or `-o` is given then a single positional argument is automatically passed to the other and two positional arguments raises a redundancy error while if both `-i` and `-o` are given, then any positional arguments raises the redundancy error).

Note: the script as currently written does not accept any positional arguments, though it does accept other flags, some with arguments some without, besides the ones related to the input and output file.

Is this possible with argparse (and if so, how) or do I have to rewrite the argument parsing using something else (and if so, what do you suggest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with the `FileType` will be awkward.  That `type` opens or creates the file.  So potentially you'll have 4 open files when you only want 2.  But if one of those files is `stdin` or `out` you don't want to close it.  And you can't handle a `positional` which could either be read or write depending what other arguments are given.

You could try defining 4 default string arguments, 2 flagged, and 2 `nargs='?'` positional.  Give them different `dest`.  Then you can apply your intelligence to the 4 possible values.  The default default `None` should be a clear enough indication that a value wasn't provided.  Once you've decided on the two filenames, then you can open and use them.  Newer Python recommends using `with` contexts, though that can be awkward when a file is already open (e.g. `sys.stdin`).

I don't think you should try to implement that logic within `argparse`.  Do it after parsing.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'd already written a bash wrapper script which used this model when additional edits to the script made me realize that I was processing the options twice, once in the wrapper and once in the script itself.  I figured it would be better for maintenance if I could have all argument parsing in one place, so now I'm trying to figure out the best way to do in python what I had done haphazardly in bash.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in a more explicit answer, here is how I eventually implemented @hpaulj's suggestion:

First I defined an argument group for the input and output file arguments:

```
files = parser.add_argument_group('file arguments:',description='These arguments can also be provided as postional arguments, in which case the input file comes first.')
files.add_argument('-i', '--input', nargs='?',
                    help='Source of the words to be syllabified.  If None or -, then input will be read from stdin.',
                    dest='inputfile')
files.add_argument('-o', '--output-file', nargs='?',
                    help='Destination of the syllabified words.  If None or -, then ouput will be written to stdout.',
                    dest='outputfile')
files.add_argument('fileone',nargs='?',
                     help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
files.add_argument('filetwo',nargs='?',
                     help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

This allowed me to keep the arguments together, separate from the other arguments for the program, and provided a bit more control over how the help text would appear so that it would make the most sense.

Then, after parsing the arguments (`args = parser.parse_args()`), I added the following logic to figure out what the correct input and output were and to open files or stdin and stdout as appropriate:

```
if (args.inputfile == None or args.inputfile == '-'):
    if (args.outputfile == None or args.outputfile == '-'):
        if (args.fileone == None or args.fileone == '-') and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = sys.stdin
            output = sys.stdout
        elif args.fileone != None and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            try:
                input = open(args.fileone,'r')
                output = sys.stdout
            except:
                input = sys.stdin
                output = open(args.fileone,'w')
        else:
            input = open(args.fileone,'r')
            output = open(args.filetwo,'w')
    else:
        if (args.fileone == None or args.fileone == '-') and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = sys.stdin
            output = open(args.outputfile,'w')
        elif args.fileone != None and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = open(args.fileone,'r')
            output = open(args.outputfile,'w')
        else:
            print("Error: too many files")
            print("Both -o and positional output file given")
            sys.exit(1)
else:
    if (args.outputfile == None or args.outputfile == '-'):
        if (args.fileone == None or args.fileone == '-') and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = open(args.inputfile,'r')
            output = sys.stdout
        elif args.fileone != None and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = open(args.inputfile,'r')
            output = open(args.fileone,'w')
        else:
            print("Error: too many files")
            print("Both -i and positional input file give")
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        if (args.fileone == None or args.fileone == '-') and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            input = open(args.inputfile,'r')
            output = open(args.outputfile,'w')
        elif args.fileone != None and (args.filetwo == None or args.filetwo == '-'):
            print("Error: too many files")
            print("Both -i and -o given with a positional file")
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print("Error: too many files")
            print("Both -i and -o given with positional files")
            sys.exit(1)
```

As you can see I decided to accept both the default `None` and `-` as possibilities for referring to stdin/stdout.  This duplicated the behavior of the `FileType` argument which also accepted `-` in this fashion.

The one ambiguity that remains is that `"None"` (i.e. a string of the word "None") is not the same as `None` (i.e. the NoneType class) and the help messages might be interpreted to imply that `-i None` should refer to stdin.  However, I figured that the difference here should be obvious enough to most python users that I wasn't going to complicate the logic any further to account for this possibility.